# Updating Views through AsyncTasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

Below is working sample code of an Android Activity that has 2 buttons, of which only 1 is ever visible: a refresh button and a stop button.

This code does the following:

Refresh is clicked: start some AsyncTasks. The preExecute of the tasks will hide the refresh button and show the stop button. The postExecute of the task will check if there are no more running tasks and if so, show the refresh button and hide the stop button.

Stop is clicked: all tasks are cancelled, the refresh button is shown and the stop button is hidden.

This code works fine, but for one exception: when I recreate the activity while a task is running by changing the screen orientation. The buttons will now return to the state as defined in the xml (refresh=visibile, stop=gone).

Using a static variable to keep track of the current state of the visibility only makes it worse, because the running Task that has to toggle it back, can only modify views in the calling activity, which has been stopped or destroyed at that point!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private static List<MyAsyncTask> activeTasks = new LinkedList<MyAsyncTask>();

    private View refresh;
    private View stop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.refresh = findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        this.refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {   // Start a couple tasks
                new MyAsyncTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
                new MyAsyncTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
            }
        });
        this.stop = findViewById(R.id.stop);
        this.stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            { // Cancel all tasks and toggle refresh button
                cancelAll();
                MainActivity.this.enableRefresh(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void enableRefresh(boolean enable)
    {
        if (this.refresh != null && this.stop != null)
        {
            this.refresh.setVisibility(enable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            this.stop.setVisibility(!enable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }

    public static void cancelAll()
    {
        for (MyAsyncTask task : MainActivity.activeTasks)
            task.cancel(true);
        MainActivity.activeTasks = new LinkedList<MyAsyncTask>();
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        private MainActivity activity;

        public MyAsyncTask(MainActivity activity)
        {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            MainActivity.activeTasks.add(this);
            this.activity.enableRefresh(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... v)
        {
            try
            { // Simulate a task
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v)
        {
            MainActivity.activeTasks.remove(this);
            if (MainActivity.activeTasks.size() == 0)
                this.activity.enableRefresh(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this link http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html by Tony Stark is probably the best solution, because that potentially solves even more problems.

However, I think I came up with an simpler solution for the problem at hand:

Add static vars to MainActivity:

```
private static MainActivity current;
private static boolean enableRefresh = true;
```

Save input value of enableRefresh():

```
public static void enableRefresh(boolean enableRefresh)
{
    MainActivity.enableRefresh = enableRefresh;
    (...) // Same as before
}
```

Add to MainActivity onCreate():

```
MainActivity.current = this;
enableRefresh(enableRefresh);
```

In the AsyncTask, use
MainActivity.current as the activity to update, instead of the activity provided in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

See this it will help you ... on handling the states in orientation change

Answer (score 0):

to handle AsyncTasks on screen orientation follow this example

```
MyAsyncTask myasynce;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.refresh = findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        this.refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {   
                //Register new Task
                myasynce = ( MyAsyncTask ) new MyAsyncTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
            }
        });
        this.stop = findViewById(R.id.stop);
        this.stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            { // Cancel all tasks and toggle refresh button
                cancelAll();
                MainActivity.this.enableRefresh(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

now `onSaveInstanceState` add

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
          super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

//put myasynce status true if still runing false if finished          
outState.putBoolean("myasynce", ( myasynce != null && query.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED ) ? true : false );
 if ( myasynce != null )
{
  myasynce.cancel(true); 
}
}
```

on `savedInstanceState`

add

```
    if ( savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myasynce") == true )
    {
//if task was running before screen orientation run it again
       myasynce = ( MyAsyncTask ) new MyAsyncTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
    }
```

hope this help

Comment: If I understand correctly, this attempts to cancel and rerun the task  whenever the activity gets recreated. That doesn't seem right.